# Proving a function is differentiable using L'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: real-analysis

> **Question:** Define
>   $$
> f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
> & \frac{\tan(x)-x}{x^2}  &&: x \ne 0 \\
> &0 &&: x = 0
> \end{aligned}
> \right.$$
>
> Show $f'(0)$ exists.

**My Attempt:**

So I begin by using the definition but I immediately come to an obstacle because I would have to divide by zero.

If I ignore that and continue and use L'Hôpital's rule, I get $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sec^2(h)-1}{3h^2}$.

Where am I going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Your second limit is equal to $\dfrac{1}{3\cos^2(h)}\cdot\left(\dfrac{\sin(h)}{h}\right)^2$ Another option would be continuing L'H.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see that! Must be the time of night haha! Thank you very much. I am correct in saying that the derivative is $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: @DavidP That's not the second limit. The second limit is equal to the limit of that expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. You just have to apply L'Hopital's rule two more times. Also, you are not ignoring the obstacle by applying L'Hopital's rule, you are dealing with the obtacle by applying L'Hopital's rule!

Comment: Thank you very much! I am correct in saying that the derivative is $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Yes, the derivative will be $1/3$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Taylor's expansion* at order $3$: $\tan x=x+\dfrac{x^3}3+o(x^3)$, hence
$$\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}= \frac{\dfrac{x^3}3+o(x^3)}{x^3}=\frac13+o(1)\to\frac13.$$